# pip is not allowing me to install seccomplite

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pip, seccomp

I tried to install seccomplite package with pip. instead I got these errors. Please help.

> Collecting seccomplite
>     Using cached seccomplite-0.1.0a3.tar.gz
>   Installing collected packages: seccomplite
>     Running setup.py install for seccomplite ... error
>       Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-HRGD9U/seccomplite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-JqYhgy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_ext
>       building 'seccomplite' extension
>       creating build
>       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
>       gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DMODULE_NAME="seccomplite" -DMAJOR_VERSION="0" -DMINOR_VERSION="1" -DDEVELOP_VERSION="0a3" -DMODULE_DESCRIPTION="lightweight libseccomp2 python bridge" -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c filter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/filter.o
>       gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-HRGD9U/seccomplite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-JqYhgy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-HRGD9U/seccomplite/

Comment: Did you mean for that to be formatted like a code sample? Because as it is it's kind of hard to understand.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman I did not intend it to be like that, here is more readable version http://lpaste.net/350223